# Криптография общения клиент-сервера

Tags: php, java, android, клиент-сервер, криптография

Недавно передо мной была поставлена задача:

> Осуществлять общение с сервером в зашифрованном виде.

Побродив по всяким интернетам, я смог найти довольно мало **полезной** информации на этот счёт. Большинство статей были посвящены знакомству с криптографией "по верхам" и только локально. А-ля `"Как зашифровать и расшифровать «Hello world» на Android"`. Мне же интересен процесс реализации в масштабе клиент-сервера. Причём, реализация серверной части, была поручена тоже мне, так что важно знать как реализовывать **и на клиенте(Java) и на сервере(PHP)**. В идеале осуществить схему, подобную Telegram:

1. Определяются закрытые ключи, посредством передачи открытых
2. Сообщение шифруется своим закрытым ключом локально
3. Передаётся по защищённому соединению (внутри которого оно ещё раз шифруется, используя другой алгоритм / тот же алгоритм, но с другим вектором)
4. Расшифровывается на другой стороне

Принципиальным отличием в данной схеме служит то, что в Telegram'e это выполняется по схеме `клиент-клиент` (без расшифровки на стороне сервера), у меня же в роли второго клиента должен выступать сервер.

Буду благодарен любым, особенно развёрнутым, ответам, так как в этой сфере я "не в зуб ногой".

Comment: Вам хватит просто загуглить TLS, HTTPS и Let's Encrypt

Comment: @andreymal просто защищённого соединения недостаточно, необходима энкрипция по типу алгоритма Диффи Хеллмана

Comment: это всё настраивается в пределах TLS

Comment: @andreymal не спорю, но это показалось недостаточным для заказчиков, поэтому и задал вопрос сюда

Comment: Вообще, на практике для настройки сервера достаточно загуглить любую статью по настройке nginx (Диффи Хеллман прилагается), которая обещает A+ на ssltest (это важно), а на клиенте (не важно джава или нет) просто взять любую библиотеку, умеющую в https, а дальше она сама разберётся

Comment: @andreymal спасибо за направление, для общего развития изучу, но, увы, это не подходит по требованиям заказчиков

Comment: @zTrap, вроде бы, TLS как раз и использует алгоритм Диффи-Хеллмана.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov да, это так, но мне так же необходимо дополнительное шифрование, непосредственно, перед передачей по защищённому каналу связи (в котором оно также будет шифроваться)

Comment: @zTrap, вот [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12203896/is-tls-over-tls-possible) что-то пишут про это.

Comment: @zTrap а какой смысл в «дополнительном шифровании»? Я тогда не понимаю чего вам надо и могу разве что PGP (gpg) предложить

Comment: Шифруете данные на клиенте RSA и передаете по TLS. Либо шифруете данные на клиенте любой симметрикой, сессионный ключ - RSA и передаете по TLS на сервер. DH вообще говорит не о шифровании данных, а об обмене ключами, к слову.

Comment: @zTrap, TLS все это и делает, что в дополненном вопросе добавлено.

Comment: @zTrap вы пытаетесь засунуть TLS в TLS?

Comment: @etki почитав материалы, предложенные выше, уже с уверенностью готов сказать что да, мне необходимо использовать TLS внутри TLS.

Comment: @zTrap сейчас буду немного грубым, но вы, скорее всего, просто не понимаете, как эта штука работает. Если TLS уязвим, то заворачивание TLS в TLS вас никак не спасет и удвоит (а не возведет в квадрат) усилия, необхоимые для шифрации. Если считать его неуязвимым для основных типов атак - а так он на данный момент и есть - то нет никакой необходимости его заворачивать сам в себя.

Comment: @etki да, так и есть :) (это можно понять из последнего предложения вопроса) Дочитав, сейчас, [статью](https://habrahabr.ru/post/258285/), я разобрался (понял основы). Спасибо

Comment: Что-ж, буду искать библиотеку, способную использовать TLS. Всем спасибо за материалы (и пинки в нужную сторону).

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример: [тынц](http://findevelop.blogspot.com.by/2013/04/java.html)
Тут описан пример на Java по реализации безопасного соединения.

Comment: Спасибо, полезный материал, но отметить как ответ не могу, потому что здесь рассмотрена лишь часть из вопроса. Другая часть (использование защищённого канала связи) рассмотрена выше, в комментариях, и не может быть отделена от полноценного ответа

Comment: @zTrap , т.е. надо https внутри ssh?)

Comment: "Надо" всё. Но на самом деле, учитывая многообразие протоколов и вариантов передачи выбор (у человека, который только начинает вникать в безопасность) может затянуться. Поэтому на вопросы "нужно то в том?" или "нужно это с этим?" я буду отвечать да, дабы разобраться в варианте

Comment: @zTrap, По мне, так достаточно https/rsa. Делать 2048 битный ключ и никто не расшифрует. 
Вот еще в копилку знаний:
https://intsystem.org/security/asymmetric-encryption-how-it-work/

Comment: Да, спасибо, правда, я это знаю, но будущим читателям пригодится :)

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю схему такую:

1. Авторизация на сервере кодируется RSA. На клиенте должен быть открытый ключ сервера, первое сообщение он шифрует им, в авторизационном сообщении шлет AES-ключ, ответ сервер кодирует уже открытым ключом клиента (который клиент, сообщит ему при регистрации).
2. Обмен данными - кодируем сессионным AES-ключом, который был передан на авторизации.
3. Сообщения можно шифровать отдельными временными ключами, генеря их и закрывая публичными тогда, когда вам будет надо.

Comment: И первые два пункта уже есть в TLS)